# toggle div on hover of one element, and off another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, menu

What I am trying to achieve is showing the "menu" span, when I hover on the "title" span, but only have it disappear when I leave the "header".

```
<header>
        <span id="title">
            title etc
        </span>

        <span id="menu">
            menu content etc
        </span>
</header>
```

I wrote this jquery code, and it works, except the "menu" span disappears when I leave the "title" span, not the "header"

```
$('#title').hover({
    $('#menu').toggle();
});
```

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is by restructuring your menu a bit, in your real world scenario positioning can take care of how it appears.

```
<header>  
<span id="title">
            title etc
             <span id="menu">
            menu content etc
        </span>
</span>
</header>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSuMy/)**

here is an example with a more complex one.

```
<span class="title">
            title
             <span class="menu">
                 <span class="item">menu11</span>
                <span class="item">menu12</span>
                 <span class="item">menu13</span>
        </span>
</span> <span class="title">
            title2 
             <span class="menu">
            <span class="item">menu21</span>
                <span class="item">menu22</span>
                 <span class="item">menu23</span>
        </span>
</span>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGfqX/)**

And with just css for the above structure:

```
.menu {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
}
.title {
    position:relative;
}
.title:hover .menu{
    display:block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWnBn/)**

Comment: With this, instead of using jquery, I would suggest css :hover instead to avoid javascript as a "dependency".

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$('#title').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#menu').show();
});

$('header').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menu').hide();
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/5sL5g/

Comment: Was just about to post more or less the same as an answer, for reference and example: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/